# Change django admin template for a calendar

Tags: python, django, calendar, django-templates, django-admin

I have some models, one of them it's about gym sessions,

```
class Gym_Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    icon = models.ImageField()
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, related_name="instructor")
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    short_review = models.TextField()
    long_review = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

I was wondering if I can override the listing template in the admin (localhost:8000/admin/gym_class/) to show the sessions in a calendar format based on each instance's date field **just for this model**, the other ones I would like to see them in a regular list format. The whole idea is that when someone wants to edit some info about the gym_class instances they will see a calendar instead of searching for the class in a big list.

Comment: Gym_Class > GymClass

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#installed-apps) When several applications provide different versions of the same resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence.

Comment: So you just override the django change_list.html template by putting it in `project/app/templates/app/admin/gymclass/change_list.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin template files are located in the contrib/admin/templates/admin directory.

In order to override Gym_Class, create an admin directory in your project’s templates directory. Inside admin directory, create sub-directories named [your app name]. Inside this directory create a directory names Gym_Class.

Next copy contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html to the directory that you just created.

Now start editing the file like normal HTML, setup calendar and other stuff you want to do.

[docss](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Comment: thank you, that resolved it, any suggestions on the calendar approach? I'm kind of worried about the list of gym_class'es and pagination cause I'm thinking for a calendar view you should have all the items, not just one page at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display of the django admin by [overriding the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

The template you're specifically looking to override is named `change_list.html`. This file can be found in django's package directory with the path:

**`django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html`**

You can copy the django template from its local python package directory, or [download it from django's Github repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.9/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) into one of your application's template directories, placing it in

**`<template-path>/admin/gym_class/change_list.html`**

*`<template-path>` is wherever you put templates in your project*

With the template, you can customize it as you wish without it modifying the change list layout for your other apps.